# CSS - Styling td > tr > tbody > thead inside parent element

Tags: css, css-selectors, styling

As part of our payment system there is an automatically generated notice that indicates monthly recurring payments. This is outputted on the page like this:

[image]

and is made up of the following elements:

```
#order_review > .shop_table > thead > tbody > tr > td
```

There are 4 blocks that all use the 'td' element so I've tried using `parent:last-child` to select the td element that contains the date (the one I'm trying to style). I have also tried:

```
#order_review .shop_table tbody tr:last-child {
```

and

```
#order_review .shop_table thead tbody tr td:last-child {
```

still no luck unfortunately. **Here is a screenshot of Console:**

[image]

Comment: Please post the relevant HTML code too. Also, why would `tbody` be a child of `thead`?

Comment: CSS guru here. That tbody is a sibling, not a child, of the thead. Also, seeing "parent:last-child" spelled out like that for the first time makes me want to post a separate Q&A since attaching :first-child or :last-child to the parent element and not the child element is a very, very common mistake that shows up time and again in many different questions on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Why are you trying to be so specific in your selectors?  It only bloats your code and leads to maintenance and other issues

Comment: The tbody being a child of thead was an oversight :$ - thank you for pointing this out for me, it's working without thead in the selector path: #order_review .shop_table tbody tr td:last-child {

Comment: @Pete But it also help to prevent "leakage" of styles doesn't it? Would you consider using lot's of `>`s to be a bad practice?

Comment: @Pete Hi, I needed to style only one of the four child elements that all use the same selectors so as far as I know there's no other way?

Comment: @BoltClock Hey! Thank you for clarifying this for me, just to confirm does that mean that :first-child and :last-child should only ever be joined to the nearest child element and not the parent?

Comment: @Jack Vanstone: Yes, like how you would attach a class selector to the element with that class. The pseudo-class describes the child element, not the parent element.